# placing widget in listbox/dropdown in gwt

Tags: gwt, user-interface, custom-controls, widget

i am using gwt to build my web site. 
i would like to create a dropdown/listbox that contains no just text but also images, meaning that in the drop down there will be a what ever widget that ill create.

please advise
jaimon

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with a ListBox, because it just creates an HTML < select> element.

You can use a [MenuBar](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html) that has one menu with [MenuItem](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuItem.html)s in it to simulate a dropdown with complex widgets inside it.  You will also be able to style the dropdown rather than rely on browser-styled form elements.

Comment: hi thanks, 
can i have a listbox or listbox-like with widgets?

:-)

Comment: Yes, use MenuBar instead of ListBox and place any widget you want inside the MenuItem to simulate a ListBox.  Regular ListBoxes will only allow you to specify plain text.  Or use DropDownListBox in the incubator, like Mat Gessel says.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Combobox or Suggestion box in [Advanced GWT Components](http://advanced-gwt.sourceforge.net/text-and-button.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another widget is the DropDownListBox in the GWT incubator. I have not used it, but the stated intent is to provide a rich, stylable ListBox. You can pass raw HTML to the addItem() method.

[DropDownListBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/DropDownListBox)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to use Tree inside ScrollPanel, without using nested items
Tree allows TreeItem to be a Widget