# GWT combobox with custom items

Tags: gwt, combobox

I am trying to define a combobox that shows as items, custom controls instead of standard text only items. The control used is com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox (standard GWT control) as combobox.

Looking at the Showcase http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList for example, there is a custom list with custom items. To do this, the example uses the CellList class. Is it possible to use the same technique for a combobox?

More in general, is it possible to use a combobox with custom, complex items (e.g. multi column items, custom complex items of any sort, in general a widget of my own or similar)?

I ask this using standard gwt ui controls, no Ext-GWT, no Smart GWT or others.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats wrong with cell list ??

Comment: Looks like a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766842/placing-widget-in-listbox-dropdown-in-gwt

Comment: @Baadshah: there is nothing wrong with cell list. I simply don't understand how to use it in a combobox-like control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot style GWT ListBox as it translates to HTML `<select>` element. If you still insist on feature rich combo-box like GXT then you can go with

1. GwtChosen - http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtchosen/
2. [CellList](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) with reduced height, selection mode - single and [CustomCell](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#custom-cell).
3. GWT SuggestBox - http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSuggestBox